# Raspberry Pi NoIR hangs. Only a physical power off solved

Tags: raspbian, video, raspicam

**Background Information:**

I built a smart door solution with a RPi B+ (Raspbian) which makes use of three sensors (PIR, Gyroscope [I2C] and an Ultrasound). Depending on the sensor status managed by a Python script,  I start recording a video by using the raspivid command and/or play sounds on Bluetooth speakers. I also have a USB WIFI dongle connected to the RPi.

This is how I call the Pi NoIR camera in my .sh file:

```
raspivid -w 800 -h 600 -t 15000 -o file.h264 -n -rot 270
```

**Problem description:**

The camera works fine for a while (I cannot precise for how long [2 hours maybe] nor what triggers the issue), but then it stops working. The funny thing is that I get no error message.

**What did I do to identify the root cause:**

- I tried to manually kill the child process (Raspivid) but it simply doesn't work. If I kill the parent process (.sh file) then my child process gets assigned to the PID 1 (init.d).
- I tried recording a new video in a new terminal window but the new process hangs too.
- Rebooting the Pi doesn't work neither. It says it is rebooting but it does not (not even with the -f option).
- I installed a new Pi Camera ensuring it was not a hardware or ribbon problem.

Have you ever faced this issue? How can I get it fixed?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the temperature? It may be overheating

Answer (score 1):

Raspivid has [historically had issues](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59089&p=442991) handling files over 2GB. It also has an enormous default bitrate of 17Mbps. I think it's plausible that these two factors, combined with your barebones raspivid arguments, are combining to screw things up.

[This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26729/32756) answer, and the [truly epic one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26746/32756) posted to the same question, suggest a couple of approaches of varying complexity to deal with the 2GB limitation. I don't have a camera to hand unfortunately, but I think (presuming the option is enabled/working in the current build) you should be able to segment the video into smaller chunks using the [`-segment` flag](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md):

> --segment,  -sg     Segment the stream in to multiple files
>
> Rather than creating a single file, the file is split up in to
>   segments of approximately the numer of milliseconds specified. In
>   order to provide different filenames, you should add %04d or similar
>   at the point in the filename where you want a segment count number to
>   appear. e.g:
>
> --segment 3000 -o video%04d.h264
>
> will produce video clips of approximately 3000ms (3s) long, named
>   video0001.h264, video0002.h264 etc. The clips should be seamless (no
>   frame drops between clips), but the accuracy of each clip length will
>   depend on the intraframe period, as the segments will always start on
>   an I-frame. They will therefore always be equal or longer to the
>   specified period.

I'd also strongly recommend experimenting with the -b flag to find the lowest possible quality/smallest possible files that you can accept. If you're going to record for upwards of 2 hours at a time you're going to need the space eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe it is a power consumption problem. You are using WiFi, camera and some other devices at the same time. All of these consume lots of power. I had some similar experiences and by using an external power adapter they where solved. Maybe using a USB hub with external power adapter solves your problem.

Regards

Saeed

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your comments. Power supply is fine. I have a 2A power adapter. The red led remains on all the time.