# Should I use raspivid for longer videos and do I need a spacious MicroSD?

Tags: camera, linux, raspicam, raspivid

Can I record a longer video (2h+) with `raspivid` and store it on a USB drive (100GB+) while using a small MicroSD card (8GB)?

---

Specifications:

Resolution 1080p

Framerate 30fps

Format h264

I am not sure what bitrate it has by default (which is the setting I will be using).

---

USB drive USB 3.0 Flash Drive FIT

130MB/s (although limited by rpi:s usb 2.0)

Comment: Depends on the video and the hard drive. Can you edit your question (*don't use comments*) to include the recording parameters (frame rate, resolution, bitrate, etc.) and the write speed of the hard drive?

Comment: @goobering, added the specifications in my post above

Comment: May be some useful (and related) info [in this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26714/can-i-record-a-24-hour-video-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-camera-module/26746#26746) too

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine.

The sample values provided [here on raspberrypi-spy.co.uk](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/05/capturing-hd-video-with-the-pi-camera-module/) suggest a bitrate of around 115MB per minute for raspivid at its default settings (1920x1080, 30 fps). That would put your storage requirements at something like 13.8GB for two hours worth of footage. The primary bottleneck is likely to be the Pi's USB bus, as you've already noted, but I don't think it'll be an issue with those settings.